# Modifying the Bootstrap table class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I like the spacing that comes with

```
<table class="table">
```

when using Bootstrap. BUT I would like to eliminate the rules. How would I do that?

Here is the section from the file's head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style> 
table {
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: none;
  border: 0px !important;
} 
.table {
    border: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source version (With SASS or LESS) remove it from there. If you don't then you'll need to override the properties in CSS, using something like

```
.table {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you *have* to, then use `!important` at the end (Before the semicolon), but only use this as a last resort (ie, if Bootstrap is applying them with an `!important` tag, you need one to override it)

If you need a hand, comment here and I'll help you.

Comment: I added the relevant section from the <head> section and the <style> section.

Comment: no. As per what I added above. I removed the .table {xx} as it seemed redundant. But either way, the same.

Comment: In that case, can you supply a link or a fiddle?